# char[][] Array not saving values while being assigned single Array[i] in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, overwrite

I commented my code to help you understand my logic, I basically receive a side value and I have to draw a triangle using X's to visually show its perimeter. (all sides are equal)

So while creating the individual arrays that will fill my matrix containing the drawing, some of the assignments are lost as iteration continues, keeping only the last iteration's value and filling the whole matrix with those values, this is making me lose all the previous line that make up a nice triangle drawing and I'm unable to print it into a txt file. (I can print it in console by printing inside the loop as it generates each array corresponding to a drawing line, but this is just a temporary illusion since I'm not keeping the matrix with the X's in place).

Would love if someone could help me not lose that matT[j] value and be able to store it anyhow.

Note: parent class Figura only provides an int called lado.

```
public class Triangulo extends Figura {

    char[] lineaI;
    char[] lineaT;
    char[][] matT;

    public char[][] matDibujo(int lado) {

        this.linea = new char[(lado+lado-1)]; //side int value to determine an eq. triangle base length
        lineaI = new char[linea.length]; //multiple intermediate single arrays that fill triangle diagonally
        lineaT = new char[linea.length]; //triangle base array
        matT = new char[lado][linea.length]; // matrix containing {{},{},{},{}} n individual arrays representing a row in the drawing (top to bottom)

        //Create triangle base line array 
        for (int i = 0; i < linea.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0 ) {
                linea[i] = 'X';
            } else if (i%2 == 0) {
                linea[i] = 'X';
            } else {
                linea[i] = ' ';
            }
            //Create triangle top point array
            if (i == (lado-1)) {
                lineaT[i] = 'X'; 
            } else {
                lineaT[i] = ' ';
            }
        }

        //Fill matrix with first array (top axis)
        matT[0] = lineaT;
        //Fill matrix last array (triangle base) 
        matT[lado-1] = linea;
        //System.out.println(matT[lado-1]);

        //THIS IS THE LOOP NOT SAVING CORRESPONDING lineaI full single array to matT[j], 
        //instead it's replacing every matT[j] with the last value of lineaI.

        //Create multiple arrays to fill n-sided triangle from top axis to base diagonally (parting from top axis)  
        for (int j = 1; j < (lado-1); j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < linea.length; i++) {
                if (i == (lado-1-j) ) {
                    lineaI[i] = 'X';
                } else if (i == (lado-1+j) ) {
                    lineaI[i] = 'X';
                } else {
                    lineaI[i] = ' ';
                }
            }
            matT[j] = lineaI;
        }

        //return the matrix so we can print it
        return matT;

    }

    //Dibujar en txt
    public void dibuja(char[][] matriz) {

        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(matriz[i]);      
        }

    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[][] mat;
        Triangulo t = new Triangulo();
        mat = t.matDibujo(4);
        t.dibuja(mat);

        //This is the outcome, since we lost matT[1] and got it replaced by the last lineaI contents, which should
        //only belong to matT[2]
        /*      X                     The outcome should be             X                       
              X   X                                                    X X     ---> this line is lost and
              X   X                                                   X   X    ----> replaced by this one
             X X X X                                                 X X X X                                   */

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the lineaI array value once calculated you assign it to the matT[j] and then again overwrite the same lineaI reference with new value and append to matT for every j value.
This causes the values to be overwritten and the final array value is displayed for all the intermittent rows.

To fix this you just have to reinitialize the lineaI variable to a new array on start of an iteration of every j value.

```
    for (int j = 1; j < (lado-1); j++) {
        //initialize the lineaI variable for start of new j value in loop
        lineaI = new char[linea.length]; // <----- new change
        for (int i = 0; i < linea.length; i++) {
            if (i == (lado-1-j) ) {
                lineaI[i] = 'X';
            } else if (i == (lado-1+j) ) {
                lineaI[i] = 'X';
            } else {
                lineaI[i] = ' ';
            }
            
        }
        matT[j] = lineaI;
        
    }
```